# How to set the "LAYERS" parameter of the QGIS 3 algorithm "native:mergevectorlayers"

Tags: qgis-processing, merge, qgis-3

I do not understand how to set the `LAYERS` parameter for the QGIS 3 `native: mergevectorlayers` algorithm (for **standalone python code**).

```
Merge vector layers (native:mergevectorlayers)
...
----------------
Input parameters
----------------    
LAYERS:  <QgsProcessingParameterMultipleLayers>
    Input layers

CRS:  <QgsProcessingParameterCrs>
    Destination CRS    

OUTPUT:  <QgsProcessingParameterFeatureSink>
    Merged    
----------------
Outputs
----------------    
OUTPUT:  <QgsProcessingOutputVectorLayer>
```

The help `processing.algorithmHelp('native:mergevectorlayers')` says that this parameter has the data type [QgsProcessingParameterMultipleLayers](https://qgis.org/api/classQgsProcessingParameterMultipleLayers.html#details), but I do not understand how to use it.

Is this a list of the `QgsVectorLayer` objects?

Seems not because I can't execute the following code:

```python
import sys
import qgis.core
qgis.core.QgsApplication.setPrefixPath(r'C:\OSGeo4W64\apps\qgis', True)
qgs = qgis.core.QgsApplication([], False)
qgs.initQgis()
sys.path.append(r'C:\OSGeo4W64\apps\qgis\python\plugins')
import processing
processing.core.Processing.Processing.initialize()
qgis.core.QgsApplication.processingRegistry().addProvider(qgis.analysis.QgsNativeAlgorithms())


input_files_list = [r"W:\MODIS\shp_files\MOD03_2018-01-01.shp",
                    r"W:\MODIS\shp_files\MOD03_2018-01-02.shp",]
layers_list = []
for num, file in enumerate(input_files_list):
    layer_name = 'layer_' + str(num)
    print(layer_name, file)
    layer = qgis.core.QgsVectorLayer(file, layer_name, 'ogr')
    print(layer)
    layers_list.append(layer)
    print('')

print('layers_list=', layers_list)
print('It seems that the script is stopped in the next line')
in_layers = qgis.core.QgsProcessingParameterMultipleLayers(layers_list)
print('This will not be printed')

output_file_path = r"W:\MODIS\shp_files\Merged.shp"
out_layer = qgis.core.QgsVectorLayer(output_file_path, 'out_layer', 'ogr')

params = {'LAYERS': in_layers,
          'OUTPUT': out_layer,}

feedback = qgis.core.QgsProcessingFeedback()

alg_name = 'native:mergevectorlayers'

print('='*50)
print(processing.algorithmHelp(alg_name))
print('='*50)
res = processing.run(alg_name, params, feedback=feedback)
print('='*50)
print(res['OUTPUT'])

qgs.exitQgis()
```

**UPDATE 1:**
I changed my **stand-alone python code** to check if I can pass parameters as a clear shapefile pathes, code execution gives this error:

```
Unable to execute algorithm
Incorrect parameter value for LAYERS
```

Here is new code:

```python
import sys
import qgis.core
qgis.core.QgsApplication.setPrefixPath(r'C:\OSGeo4W64\apps\qgis', True)
qgs = qgis.core.QgsApplication([], False)
qgs.initQgis()
sys.path.append(r'C:\OSGeo4W64\apps\qgis\python\plugins')
import processing
processing.core.Processing.Processing.initialize()
qgis.core.QgsApplication.processingRegistry().addProvider(qgis.analysis.QgsNativeAlgorithms())

in_layers = [r"W:\MODIS\shp_files\MOD03_2018-01-01.shp",
             r"W:\MODIS\shp_files\MOD03_2018-01-02.shp",]
output_file_path = r"W:\MODIS\shp_files\Merged.shp"
params = {'LAYERS': in_layers,
          'OUTPUT': output_file_path,}
feedback = qgis.core.QgsProcessingFeedback()
alg_name = 'native:mergevectorlayers'    
res = processing.run(alg_name, params, feedback=feedback)    
print(res)    
qgs.exitQgis()
```

Comment: it works when the path to layers has only single forward slashes /

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's literally just a list of QgsVectorLayer objects, or a list of layer paths, E.g.

```
in_layers =  [r'W:\MODIS\shp_files\MOD03_2018-01-01.shp',
              r'W:\MODIS\shp_files\MOD03_2018-01-02.shp',]
```

In the case of a geopackage, you must specify the `layername` like that:

```
in_layers =  [r'C:/path/layer1.gpkg|layername=layer1',
              r'C:/path/layer2.gpkg|layername=layer2'],
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, but the script does not work as a stand-alone code. It works well in the QGIS python console. It seems that this is an initialization problem. I can not understand how to make it work as a stand-alone code (without QGIS python console).

Comment: Try in a nightly of QGIS 3.2 - there's much more explicit errors messages in 3.2 and there may be clues there.