# What type of object QGIS native:mergevectorlayers accepts for LAYER parameter?

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis, qgis-processing

Here is part of the code which I am using:

```
from qgis.processing import alg
from qgis.core import *
import processing

@alg(name="ex_new", label=alg.tr("Example script (new style)"), group="examplescripts", group_label=alg.tr("Example Scripts"))
@alg.input(type=alg.MULTILAYER, name="INPUT", label="Input layer")
@alg.input(type=alg.VECTOR_LAYER_DEST, name="OUTPUT", label="crowns")

def testalg(instance, parameters, context, feedback, inputs):
    """
    Description goes here. (Don't delete this! Removing this comment will cause errors.)
    """
    mergelayer_params = {'LAYERS':['INPUT'], 'CRS': QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem('EPSG:2180'), 'OUTPUT':parameters['OUTPUT']}
    
    mergedlayer_result = processing.run('native:mergevectorlayers', mergelayer_params, context=context, feedback=feedback)
 
    return {'OUTPUT': mergedlayer_result['OUTPUT']}
```

I am trying to pass multiple .shp files with `QgsProcessingParameterMultipleLayers` with `alg.MULTILAYER` to process `native:mergevectorlayers`.
But it returns error

`Invalid parameter value for LAYERS`.

I was thinking that with `QgsProcessingParameterMultipleLayers` I am passing a list which should work for used processing algorithm. What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*It's literally just a list of `QgsVectorLayer` objects, or a list of layer paths*, [@ndawson](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/286159/29431) says.

Accordingly, use this way:

```
from qgis.processing import alg
from qgis.core import *
import processing

@alg(name="ex_new", label=alg.tr("Example script (new style)"), group="examplescripts", group_label=alg.tr("Example Scripts"))
@alg.input(type=alg.MULTILAYER, name="INPUT", label="Input layer")
@alg.input(type=alg.VECTOR_LAYER_DEST, name="OUTPUT", label="crowns")

def testalg(instance, parameters, context, feedback, inputs):
    """
    Description goes here. (Don't delete this! Removing this comment will cause errors.)
    """

    # Add this line
    layers = instance.parameterAsLayerList(parameters, 'INPUT', context)
        
    mergelayer_params = {'LAYERS': layers, ## <-- change ['INPUT'] to layers
                         'CRS': QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem('EPSG:2180'), 
                         'OUTPUT':parameters['OUTPUT']}
    
    mergedlayer_result = processing.run('native:mergevectorlayers',
                                         mergelayer_params,
                                         context=context,
                                         feedback=feedback)
 
    return {'OUTPUT': mergedlayer_result['OUTPUT']}
```

Comment: Well thanks for everything, works flawlessly. I am learning custom scripts in QGIS, especially in that format. It seems pretty much confusing for me. I have followed some code snippets and I was sure that by using `['INPUT']` it would be enough to pass list. Well nevertheless, thanks for claryfying